# Determine if workspace exists on build server

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-task

Is it possible to determine whether a workspace exist on the server given the local path using **tf.exe**?

This can be done using the TFS API but that would require me to build the task source code before using it which is not possible because I don't have a workspace yet. Checking binaries into source control is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Why do you need to know this? As for the workspaces that you own, you can view them through Visual Studio. The workspaces used by the build server are set on the build agent, so don't need to do anything special to determine what directories the build server is using.

Answer (score 4):

If you run the `tf.exe workfold` command passing in the local directory, it will either return an error if the folder is not mapped, or it will return the workspace information.  You can (in a hacky fashion) determine if an error occurred by redirecting the stderr to a text file, then checking to see if the file is empty.  For example:

```
tf.exe workfold c:\some\mapping\folder\path 2> error.txt
```

You may also be able to check the exit code from the command.  Based on research, it looks like the exit code is set to 100 if there's an error.  Not sure what you can do in the task, but in a CMD file you can check `ERRORLEVEL`.

To see this in action, try:

```
tf.exe workfold "C:\program files" 2> error.txt
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```